# Bind MaxWidth to calculated Auto value

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a datatemplate containing this section. The second column is used for a GridSplitter.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MaxWidth="100"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid>
```

What I am trying to do is to bind the MaxWidth of the first column to the width of its content instead of a hardcoded width value.

The idea is that the user  can make the column narrower than its content but not wider.

Is this possible with simple binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneTime Binding to Actual Width of the content UserControl did the trick!

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ColumnContent, Mode=OneTime}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid>
```